# Import Apache Commons Math library

Tags: java, apache, import, classpath, javac

I've seen so many posts about people being unable to correctly compile Java files while trying to import Apache Commons Math 3, and so far those solutions have not helped me and I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

In one file I am importing the Apache library with this commmand:
`import org.apache.commons.math3;`

I'm running the following commmand on Linux Mint:
`javac -classpath ./commons-math3-3.6/commons-math3-3.6.jar:. db/*.java`

But still I get this error every time:

```
error: package org.apache.commons does not exist 
import org.apache.commons.math3;
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Where is the jar file located, relative to where you are launching the java command?

Comment: I actually just solved it, although I'm not sure why. If I change the import statement to `import org.apache.commons.math3.*;`, it works fine. That seems strange to me, as I thought that importing without the `*` just limited what the import gave you access to.

Comment: You must be using a class that is in the math3 package. Either you have to add the class to the end like `org.apache.commons.math3.SomeClass;` or you have to add the wildcard to import all classes in that package, like `org.apache.commons.math3.*;`